# Method getting called on object's field instead of the object?

Tags: security, unicode, go

This code has some objects representing a user and the admin who created that user. It's a trimmed down version of some code submitted to us by an applicant. The code is broken and deletes the admin when you try to delete the user (as demonstrated by `main`). Why does `u.Delete` call the admin's delete instead of the user's delete?

```
package admin
import "fmt"
type Admin struct {}
func (Admin) Delete() {
    fmt.Println("deleting admin")
}
```

```
package user
import (
    "fmt"
    "admin"
)
type User struct {*admin.Admin}
func (*User) Dlete() {
    fmt.Println("deleting user")
}
```

```
package main
import (
    "admin"
    "user"
)

func main() {
    u := user.User{&admin.Admin{}}
    u.Delete()
}
```

```
$ GOPATH=`pwd` go run a.go 
deleting admin
```

Comment: Don't try to write inheritance style code with embedding. Such errors are the price for trying such stuff. You'll get bitten more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code the letter `e` in User's `Delete` method is not of the same encoding as the letter `e` in Admin's `Delete` method.  Since Go supports utf8 this is not an error but it is a different method.  Fix the `e` in User's `Delete` method and all should work as expected.

Comment: But even if they're different, say instead `Admin` has `remove` and `User` has `delete`, why would `u.remove` work?

Comment: @Dog It is a feature of the language, read [this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding). If you don't want that behavior don't embed Admin anonymously give it a name like `User{Admin Admin}` then access admin's method like `u.Admin.Remove()`

Answer (score 2):

because the method delete on the user is defined for *User  not for `User`, while Admin's Delete is defined for the non pointer `Admin`.
User embeds Admin, so it inherits `func (Admin) Delete()` method.

try using the pointer to user (notice the `&`)

```
func main() {
    u := &user.User{&admin.Admin{}}
    u.Delete()
}
```

Comment: That does the same thing.